# Substring in vim script

Tags: vim, substring, substr

Is there any `substr()` like function to get substring in vim script? If not what is the best replacement or alternative for this kind of task?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

it works like python:

```
echo '0123456'[2:4]
234
```

For detailed doc:

```
:h expr-[:]
```

Comment: Another access point to the same functionality is strpart     strpart("myfoo", 2,3) => foo

Comment: In Python, `'0123456'[2:4]` returns `23`.

Answer (score 6):

For multi-bytes characters, there is also [`:h strcharpart()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#strcharpart%28%29)

If the function does not exist in your old flavour of Vim, it could be emulated with for instance

```
function! lh#encoding#strpart(mb_string, p, l)
  " call lh#assert#value(lh#encoding#strlen(a:mb_string)).is_ge(a:p+a:l)
  return matchstr(a:mb_string, '.\{,'.a:l.'}', 0, a:p+1)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 6):

The VimL expression `mystring[a:b]` returns a substring from byte index `a` up to (and including) `b`.

But be aware that **the semantics are different from Python's [subscript notation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) or Javascript's [`str.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)**. In particular, VimL counts the bytes instead of the characters for indexing, and the byte at the end of the range (the byte at index `b`) is included.

These examples illustrate how the behavior differs:

```
              VimL        Python
--------------------------------
s = "abcdef"
s[0]          a           a
s[5]          f           f
s[0:1]        ab          a
s[2:4]        cde         cd
s[-1:]        f           f
s[:-1]        abcdef      abcde
s[-2:-1]      ef          e

s = "äöü"
s[0:2]        ä\xc3       äö
```

Also, look up the documentation at [`:help subscript`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#subscript) and `:help expr-[:]`.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether you want byte range or character range. For byte range `b` through `e` its `str[b:e]`, but for character range you'll need byteidx function:

```
str[byteidx(str,b):byteidx(str,e+1)-1]
```

For multibyte characters results differ.